# Send email from Google Workspace Catch All email

Tags: email, google-workspace

I’m currently using Apple Hide My Email to create random email addresses for each website I create an account on. I really like the privacy and spam control I can get from this feature, but the Apple email client is terrible, and the process to create a new email is also terrible, specially when I’m not on my iPhone.

I would love to simulate this whole experience using a catch-all email config through Google Workspace. However, I don’t think I would be able to reply to incoming emails using the same email address that I used to create the account.

Is there a way to send emails from the email addresses I’m creating through a catch-all config on Google Workspace? If not, would it be possible to simulate the experience I have with Apple’s Hide my Email on Google Workspace?